# How to set number of inodes during initial Centos 6 ext4 install?

Tags: linux, centos, installation, partition

There are similar questions, but nothing that was exactly on par with what I am inquiring. Completely fresh install of Centos 6, the server is setup with a BIOS RAID 1. I'm trying to set the number of inodes for the / partition during install. I've done this before with Debian, and on the partitioning screen there is an escape character you can use, to utilize mkfs, however I am unuaware of such for CentOS. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

After you've set up your [partitions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartsetup-x86.html) and the system [creates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/Write_changes_to_disk-x86.html) them, you then come to the [package selection](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-pkgselection-x86.html) screen. Here, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a [virtual console](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-guimode-virtual-consoles-x86.html) with a root shell. You can then reformat the partition to your liking. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to return to the installer when you finish.